# problems with indexPathForSelectedRow(), returns incorrect index. Using Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

Sorry for being a complete noob at all this, but I am having trouble using the indexPathForSelectedRow() within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function within a Table View.

What I'm trying to do is to capture the textLabel.text value of a cell in my table into NSUserDefaults, then transition that into a finalView. In the finalView, a label's text will be updated based on the value retrieved from the TableView.

Here's the code in my tableView:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() as NSIndexPath! //supposed to get the correct index, but doesn't

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as UITableViewCell!

    captureCellVals.setObject(cell.textLabel?.text, forKey: "restoname")

    //code to transfer to final view:

    let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finalView") as FinalView

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)




}
```

And now here is the code in the finalView:

```
 class FinalView: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let values = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let restName = values.objectForKey("restoname") as String

    Restaurant.text = restName


    }

   @IBOutlet weak var Restaurant: UILabel!

 }
```

The thing is, this actually works. It is indeed retrieving the textLabel.text value of a cell, transitioning it into the FinalView, and updating the Restaurant.text to display the retrieved name. The problem is that it retrieves the incorrect name from the table.

for example, if i click a row with restaurant name 'Cafe France', the Restaurant.text changes to 'Tonys Cafe' instead of the intended 'Cafe France'. I think it's the indexes, but could it be something else? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Why are you asking this question again? You're still doing it incorrectly. Don't get the data from the cell, and don't use NSUserDefaults for this purpose as I pointed out on your other question. There are hundreds of answers on SO about passing data between controllers, so do some searching.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use let index path = whatever. TableView's method didSelectRowAtIndexPath already has indexPath parameter.

Just change your line

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as UITableViewCell!
```

to

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
```

and delete this line

```
let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() as NSIndexPath!
```

Once again NSUserDefaults has a specific method for loading your stored string called [stringForKey()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringForKey:)

```
Restaurant.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("restoname") ?? ""
```